# python scipy stats cdf beta-pert calculation returns nan

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cdf

I am trying to calculate beta-pert with scipy.stats.beta.cdf but whenever the code below is ran it returns [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]. I need help with calculating beta-pert.

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import beta
import numpy as np
import random

random_values = np.random.randint(low=5000, high=625000, size=10)
print ('impart random' + ' ' + str(random_values) )

minimum = 5000
mode = 215000
maximum = 625000

d = (minimum + 4*mode + maximum)/6
print ("intermediate value"  + ' ' + str(d) )
alpha = 6*((d - minimum)/(maximum - minimum))
beta = 6*((maximum - d)/(maximum - minimum))

location = minimum
scale = maximum - minimum

pert = scipy.stats.beta.cdf(random_values, alpha, beta, location, scale)

print ('pert' + ' ' + str(pert))
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  When I run the code using scipy version 1.2.1 and numpy version 1.15.14, I don't get any errors or warnings, and `pert` is an array of numbers.  Have you looked at the values of the arguments that you are passing to the CDF function?  What are the values of `alpha`, `beta`, `location` and `scale`?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  If you are using Python 2, the division of the integer values will cause problems in this code.  Try adding `from __future__ import division` at the top of your script.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser, I will check this once I get home after work and let you know.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I just upgraded to scipy.__version__  '1.2.1' and numpy.version.version '1.16.2' but I am still getting an array of nan. I will keeping investigating. Thanks again.

Comment: Check your Python version.  The way your code is written, it will not work in Python 2, because of the default behavior of interger division.  It worked fine for me in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser for your time,  I will install Python 3 when I return home in the evening and hopefully it resolves the issues.

Comment: If the problem is the integer division, then Python 3 should work.  You could also make the change I suggested earlier to use the code with Python 2.

Comment: I have upgraded to python3  and it now works. I now get values instead of nan. Thanks.